# Image in source but not display in browser for the first time

Tags: html, css, angularjs, browser

I don’t know how to explain this but let me try..

Image in source but not display in browser for the first time.And when you refresh its visible.What could be the reason please tell.

- I have inspect it and is right there inside container div, I can see.
- when you load/refresh page again its always visible.
- some time its visible in even first visit,but its rare let say 1/10 times.
- Previously it was working fine with the same code.

> Please try to explain what could be the reason,if exact answer is not available.

I am using `node.js`,`angular.js` and browser is chrome Version 45. and I am sure that its related to client side.

codes

this is my div

```
          <div id='userIntro'>
            <img src='images/{{dp}}' style='display:inline;max-width: 50px;max-height: 50px;z-index:2;' ng-click='changeUserImage()' id='userDP'/>
            <br/>
            <label style='display:inline;'>Welcome {{userName}}</label>
            <input type='file' name='userImageF' id='userImageF' accept="image/*" style='display:none;' onchange="angular.element(this).scope().readImage()"/>
          </div>
```

and this is my controller function code.

```
 var uAjax = $http.get("/getUser");
        uAjax.success(function(data) {
            if (data === 'failed')
            {

                $location.url('/login');

            }
            else
            {

                $scope.userName = data.username;
                $scope.dp = '/'+data.dp;
            }
        });
```

this code was working fine previously..

[image: as you can see here]

Comment: Can you add some code snippets

Comment: actually there are lots of dependencies in code that’s why I have not post any code it may create more confusion.Just want to know how it could be possible.

Comment: code updated... please see now.

Comment: I think problem with src attrs. You use an expression so you should use ng-src. Example: `<img ng-src="image/{{url}}" ...`

Comment: ya exactly that was the problem... thank you Errorpro

Comment: you can point my answer as correct to help other people find answer on the same question.

Comment: how .. i already upvote you comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem with src attrs. You use an expression so you should use ng-src. Example: `<img ng-src="image/{{url}}" ...`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/r904fnb3/2/

```
var deffered = $q.defer();
setTimeout(function(){
deffered.resolve('https://angularjs.org/img/AngularJS-large.png');
}, 3000);    
//promise
deffered.promise.then(function(res){
    console.log(res);
    vm.image = res;
});
```

You can use $q deffred service that will take care of your image varialbe
hope this may help you

Comment: thnx.. not for this but this will help me :)

Answer (score 0):

As mention in comment by Errorpro.

The problem was of `src`... as I am using expression, it should be `ng-src`.

thnx Errorpro.